# Construct a complete binary tree from given integer array in C

Tags: c, queue, binary-tree

I get unexpected output in the code for the following problem:

Construct a complete (or almost complete) binary tree from given integer array.
Use a linked list representation of a queue.

*Complete binary tree* is *full BT*, and all leafs are on the same level.
*Almost complete BT* doesn't have to be *full BT*, and all leafs are on the same level.

#### Example 1: Almost Complete BT

```
arr[]={10,9,-5,1,2}

    Tree:
    10
   /  \
  9   -5
 / \
1   2
```

#### Example 2: Complete BT

```
arr[]={10,9,-5,1,2,7,4}

Tree:

    10
   /  \
  9   -5
 / \  /  \
1   2 7   4
```

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_tree
{
    int info;
    struct node_tree *left,*right;
}TREE_NODE;

typedef struct node_queue
{
    TREE_NODE *tn;
    struct node_queue *next;
}QUEUE_NODE;

TREE_NODE *newTN(int info)
{
    TREE_NODE *newN=(TREE_NODE*)malloc(sizeof(TREE_NODE));
    newN->left=newN->right=0;
    newN->info=info;
    return newN;
}

void push_queueN(QUEUE_NODE **pf,QUEUE_NODE **pr,TREE_NODE *tn)
{
    QUEUE_NODE *newQN=(QUEUE_NODE*)malloc(sizeof(QUEUE_NODE));
    newQN->tn=tn;
    newQN->next=0;
    if(*pf==0)
      *pf=*pr=newQN;
    else
    {
        (*pr)->next=newQN;
        *pr=newQN;
    }
}

int pop_queueN(QUEUE_NODE **pf,QUEUE_NODE **pr,TREE_NODE **tn)
{
    if(*pf==0)
        return 0;
    QUEUE_NODE *p=*pf;
    *tn=p->tn;
    if(*pf==*pr)
        *pf=*pr=0;
    else
        *pf=p->next;
    free(p);
    return 1;
}

TREE_NODE *complete(int *arr,int n)
{
    TREE_NODE *root;
    QUEUE_NODE *pf=0,*pr=0;
    int check=0,i;
    int *p=arr;

    if(p==NULL)
        root=NULL;

    root=newTN(arr[0]);
    push_queueN(&pf,&pr,root);

    p++;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

       TREE_NODE *parent=pf->tn;
       if(pop_queueN(&pf,&pr,&parent))
            check=1;
       else
            check=0;
       TREE_NODE *leftChild=NULL,*rightChild=NULL;
       leftChild=newTN(&p);
       push_queueN(&pf,&pr,leftChild);
       p++;
       if(p)
       {
         rightChild=newTN(&p);
         push_queueN(&pf,&pr,rightChild);
         p++;
       }

       parent->left=leftChild;
       parent->right=rightChild;
    }

    return root;
}

int height(TREE_NODE *root)
{
    if(root==0)
        return 0;
    int hl=height(root->left);
    int hr=height(root->right);

    return 1+(hl>hr?hl:hr);
}

void printCurrLevel(TREE_NODE *root,int level)
{
   if(root==0)
        return;
   if(level==1)
        printf("%d",root->info);
   else if(level>1)
   {
      printCurrLevel(root->left,level-1);
      printCurrLevel(root->right,level-1);
   }
}

void levelOrder(TREE_NODE *root)
{
   int h=height(root),i;

   for(i=1;i<=h;i++)
      printCurrLevel(root,i);

}

int main()
{
    int arr[]={10,9,-5,1,2};
    int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    TREE_NODE *root;
    root=complete(arr,n);
    levelOrder(root);

    return 0;
}
```

There are some issues with pointers in function `complete()`.

Could someone point out where are the possible errors?

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings. in `complete` `p` is `int*`. You're invoking `newTN` in two different locations in that function using `&p`, which is obviously wrong, as `newTN` takes `int`, not `int**. I think you want `*p` in both of those calls.